# The Clean programming language in the real world?

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language

Are there any real world applications written in the [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/) programming language? Either open source or proprietary.

Comment: This question was also asked on the Clean mailing list. See [here](https://mailman.science.ru.nl/pipermail/clean-list/2003/002535.html) for an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a direct answer, but when I checked last time (and I find the language very interesting) I didn't find anything ready for real-world.

The idealist in myself always wants to try out new languagages, very hot on my list (apart from the aforementioned very cool Clean Language) is currently (random order) [IO](http://www.iolanguage.com/), [Fan](http://www.fandev.org/) and [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)...

But in the meantime I then get my pragmatism out and check the [Tiobe Index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html). I know you can discuss it, but still: It tells me what I will be able to use in a year from now and what I possibly won't be able to use...

No pun intended!

Comment: Very true. Just ordered a book on Scala. But my daily bread I earn on C++. Thanks for the links to IO and Fan.

Comment: Good to see that Haskell and F# are now in top 50! But why on earth is C still on rank 2?? Anyway - I found CLEAN via a benchmark of programming languages web site. And there it outperformed haskell.... so I decided to give it a try. Also windows support seems to be better in CLEAN compared to haskell and the IO is done not with monads but with uniqueness types. I remember that all that monad talk was a big hurdle when I started Haskell... Also they have destructive array updates - a bit like in ML which might gain performance for numerical applications.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Clean together with the iTasks library to build websites quite easy around workflows.

But I guess another problem with Clean is the lack of documentation and examples: "the Clean book" is from quite a few years back, and a lot of new features don't get documented except for the papers they publish.

Answer (score 4):

http://clean.cs.ru.nl/Projects page doesn't look promising :) It looks like just another research project with no real-world use to date.

Comment: I am sometimes fascinated by the fact that certain language do not get mainstream while others do. Often an important factor is the size of the company promoting them. Clean looks very interesting to me but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be wide spread.

Comment: Consider that a few years ago Microsoft got interested in OCaml and made F#.

Answer (score 3):

As one of my professors at college has been involved in the creation of Clean, it was no shock  he'd created a real world application. The rostering-program of our university was created entirely in Clean.

Comment: So this indicates that Clean can easily be used for "real-world" applications (whatever that means).

Comment: Indeed... Still it's probably easier to use a more "common" language like C#

Comment: I agree. C# has a big community and there are high chances that you can learn it in school or at your workplace: these are big advantages. I find Clean interesting (especially because of uniqueness types) but I have never had enough time / motivation to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

The Clean IDE and the Clean compiler are written in Clean. (http://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Download_Clean)

Answer (score 2):

[Cloogle](https://cloogle.org), a search engine for Clean libraries, syntax, etc. (like Hoogle for Haskell) is written in Clean. Its source is on Radboud University's GitLab instance ([web frontend](https://gitlab.science.ru.nl/cloogle/cloogle-org); [engine](https://gitlab.science.ru.nl/cloogle/Cloogle)).